# Cauchy-Schwarz application

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. I need to show that

$$\left(\int_1^ef(x)dx \right)^2 \leq \int_1^e xf(x)^2dx$$ I have been trying to use C-S to prove this but with no luck.

Comment: what did you try? There's only one way to apply Cauchy Schwarz here and it would work. Hint: What should you multiply to $xf(x)^2$ so that the square root of product is $f(x)$?

Comment: @Soarer I used the fact $\sqrt{x} \geq 1$ and got as far as I mention in response to DJC

Comment: @Soarer I posted a hint as an answer before I saw your comment. Now I deleted it.

Comment: @user9352, you may try to answer the hint I mentioned in the last comment.

Comment: @Soarer You can maybe post the hint as an answer?

Comment: @Srivatsan as there's an answer now it's okay I think.

Comment: @Soarer Sorry for butting in line, I didn't notice your hint when I posted...

Comment: @Byron It doesn't matter who posts an answer as long as it's correct and OP understands it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\left(\int_1^ef(x)dx \right)^2 = \left(\int_1^e{1\over\sqrt{x}}\cdot \sqrt{x}f(x)dx \right)^2 \leq \int_1^e{1\over x}\,dx\cdot\int_1^e xf(x)^2dx=\int_1^e xf(x)^2dx$$

Comment: I would just like to mention for completeness that the inequality is due to Cauchy-Schwarz and the equality on the right comes from integrating 1/x.